# But then,but then again,then again

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, difference

I am confused about those but then ,but then again and then again.Can I use them interchanggeably?what I understand is those are similar as Although.Can I use them as although when I translate sentence.if I am wrong pls correct me.

1.I would like to go abroad but then I am afraid of going abroad.

2.I keep learning English but then again I know myself my English is weak.

3.People like talent person then again they never neglect normal person.

Correct me!

Comment: Would you please improve your question by including your own research. What does your dictionary say? What don't you understand? Please add some examples of the use of those phrases you found. Their meaning is context dependent.

Comment: It's no different to ***on the other hand*** (or as Lewis Carroll might have it — [***contrariwise***](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/16478-contrariwise-continued-tweedledee-if-it-was-so-it-might-be)). Some combinations are more likely than others, but they're mostly just repetition for the sake of it.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

(Collins Dictionary, paraphrased)

1. You use 'but then' or 'but then again' before a remark contradicting/offering another perspective for the previous statement.
   example: I think it's too hot for a run right now, but then again, I'm also wearing a jacket.

(merriam webster dictionary, paraphrased)
2. For a statement that adds a different thought to the preceding statement
example: I'm surprised to hear that Tom has left the army. But then I suppose he never was the type to obey orders.

**Overall: They seem basically identical.** 'But then again' should usually be followed by a comma, though.

(Correct me if not, but I can't find anything suggesting otherwise.)

Comment: Thank you very much.